# How to give an argument when a condition has been met in PHP?

Tags: php, arguments, conditional-statements

When i want to mail my users to notify them of some event, i will call the mail() function in PHP. I want to give the mail function a fifth argument, but since this is disabled when in safe_mode, the mail() function will return false when giving this argument. My question is basically:

How can i write this piece of code:

```
if (!$bSafeMode) {
    mail($sTo, $sSubject, $sBody, $sHeader, $sFifthArgument);
} else {
    mail($sTo, $sSubject, $sBody, $sHeader);
}
```

But in a way like this:

```
mail($sTo, $sSubject, $sBody, $sHeader, (!$bSafeMode? $sFifthArgument : ''));
```

Obviously this code i showed you doesn't work, but i want to know if there is something similar to this, so that i can keep my code tidier.

And please don't argue with me as to why i want it this way and why i want to check for safe_mode and stuff. I just do, i only want to know if what i want is possible and how i would go about doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would argue that your first piece of code looks just fine.

Comment: Your second example seems fine, except that you would normally pass `NULL` instead of the `''` empty string for absent parameters. Another workaround option was `call_user_func_array`, but wouldn't really qualify as "tidier".

Comment: If you don't want arguments that might help us understand what the goal is, then maybe a public format like SO isn't for you? I don't see the difference between the first and the second form, only that the second doesn't work. What is the essential part of the first `if` that's wrong, so we can actually think with you?

Comment: @mario Depends how `mail()` checks the arguments internally when safe mode is enabled.

Comment: I'm not saying that the first part is wrong at all, I'm just saying that if i can do it in 1 line would be better than doing it in two(IMHO).

Comment: The reason why said i wanted no arguments is solely because everytime i ask a question here ppl start to ask me why i want to it in the first place. I don't want to have to explain everytime WHY i want to do something. I just want to know if it is possible or not. I just figured that if i said "no arguments" that it would solve this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course, you can do something like

```
$args = array('foo', 'bar');
if($blah) $args[] = 'baz';
call_user_func_array('mail', $args);
```

but I don't think this is anyhow better than your first snippet

Comment: Considering mail() is a PHP function; wouldn't call_user_func_array bail out telling you it expects a valid callback? At least I though it could only work with user defined functions (as the name might imply), I could be wrong though?

Comment: hmm; -edit+snip- yeah, doc clearly states it doesn't work for echo heh. Should indeed work for mail :)

Comment: Your answer was the only working answer to my question, although it is indeed not the cleanest option. I decided to stick with my first if-else construction in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to pass `null` to the function (in the case of mail that's the default value too for the fifth argument as far as I know).

So it'd be like: `mail($sTo, $sSubject, $sBody, $sHeader, (!$bSafeMode ? $sFifthArgument : null));` That should be allowed. See also as example: http://codepad.org/HerLr9O4 :)

As Phil mentioned in the comment below; it will probably check for the passed amount of parameters (I can't test this here; but I would expect that). That basically means you're stuck with the if-else; which is perfectly readable (and maybe even better documentable too!) :).

Comment: I have a feeling the safe mode check will be using `argc` to determine the number of arguments internally in which case passing `null` will still count as 5. Would need to test to be sure

Comment: Ah, I see I partly misread the question. Didn't think the $bSafeMode would be linked to the php safe_mode configuration... In that case you are (unfortunately) right; and then there is no other way then the if-else construction.